# how to create query with missing attribute in table?

Tags: sql

I am creating a query in which I want to take n columns from table a and m columns from table b. card(a) < card(b) and I'm matching their IDs. This works fine, but I want some tuples from table b that match my other condition but those who match my other condition are not tuples from table a but solely from table b. The problem is that query won't execute because the other tuples are missing an attribute that I want to be in the table.

example:

table a:

| ID | Name | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1923 | david | google.com |

table b:

| idd | power | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1923 | 1 | 4000 |
| 1234 | 5 | 5600 |
| 2342 | 23 | 34234 |

result:

| idd | domain | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1923 | google.com | 4000 |
| 1234 | null | 5600 |

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hope this is better

Comment: And what happens to 2342?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for a `left join` with filtering.  Something like this:

```
select b.id, a.domain, b.value
from b left join
     a
     on b.id = a.id
where b.value < 10000
```